# Within a range in Excel, copy cell value based on lookup

Tags: excel, range, lookup

I'm trying to do a list of combinations of author IDs in the range of a publication. Example of data:

```
+--------+--------------+----------+
| PublID | Author       | AuthorID | 
+--------+--------------+----------+
| 1      | Author, A    | 1        |
| 1      | Foo, A       | 2        |
| 1      | Bar, C       | 3        |
| 2      | Some, A      | 4        |
| 2      | Else, B      | 5        |
| 3      | Writer, AB   | 6        |
| 4      | Smith, B     | 7        |
| 4      | Smith, C     | 8        |
+--------+--------------+----------+
```

The idea in pseudo code:

```
for every PublID
 for every first AuthorID
   copy it in the Source column
   copy the next AuthorID in the Target column
```

so, this is what I'm after:

```
+--------+--------+
| Source | Target |
+--------+--------+
| 1      |  1     |
| 1      |  2     |
| 1      |  3     |
| 2      |  4     |
| 2      |  5     |
| 3      |  6     |
| 4      |  7     |
| 4      |  8     |
+--------+--------+
```

I'm familiar with VLOOKUP, and while at this case, I've also experimented with MATCH, INDEX and OFFSET - but if you can give any pointers on where to start and what to avoid, that'd help me a lot. I'd imagine that I'd first need to define the range, then within the range, do the lookup(s), and then define the range again.

Being a somewhat newbie with Excel functions, I'm not sure if I'd actually be better off with some VB macro solution instead. But, that'd be another story then.

Comment: The Source and Target columns are just a copy of the PublId and AuthorId columns. It's not that simple is it?

Comment: Gosh! How could I miss such an obvious thing [blush]. Thanks, you are a genius.